# How to write into nth line in a file with python

Tags: python

I wanted to write a line at particular line number, my file contains following data

```
one
two
three
four
five
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine
Ten
Eleven
```

Here is my code -

```
f = open("file.txt",'r+')
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i == 2:
        f.write("Added at 2nd line")
    elif i == 3:
        f.write("Added at 2nd line")
    elif i > 29:
        break
f.close()
```

after running above code i am getting O/P as below

```
one
two
three
four
five
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine
Ten
ElevenAdded at 2nd line
```

Please help me how to write to particular;ar number in file

Comment: what do you mean by nth line, are you replacing a line, adding a line?

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear.  Do you want to overwrite starting at the second line, or insert lines, or replace lines?  The first is trivial, the other two basically require you to rewrite the rest of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Ihave tried it and it actually works, and really quickly

Go through the concept..

[linecache](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html)

and if not this..then this is what u need to do:

Files in Python are iterators, meaning they can be looped over, or have iteration operations applied to them.

To get every 5th line, for example, would be:

```
import itertools

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    fifthlines = itertools.islice(f, 0, None, 5)
    for line in fifthlines:
        # do something with line
```

To skip a series of lines, use a noop for loop; here we skip 10 lines, then read 10:

```
for _ in itertools.islice(f, 0, 10):
    pass

for line in itertools.islice(f, 0, 10):
    # do something with this 10th line
```

With the itertools library, and a quick scan through the Python tutorial you can figure out the rest of the script easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me, but this is the way i understand it. I tried to use your approach with enumerate and new variable line_num (your line number) which you can set manually in the script or from the terminal:

```
main_file = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = []
line_num = 4 # if you want set it manually from script
#line_num = input('Type the line number: ') # if you want to set it from terminal

for i, line in enumerate(main_file): 
    if i+1 != line_num:
        str_line = line
    else:
        # enumerate starts from zero so increment i by 1
        str_line = line.rstrip('\n')  + ' (added at %s line)\n' % (i+1) 
    lines.append(str_line)
    if i > 29: 
        break 

main_file.close()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as main_file:
    main_file.writelines(lines)
```

I've divided work with files into two blocks:
- first is reading file lines and adds it to lines list (with added edited line)
- and second block is writing lines into files.txt writelines method concluded in with statement.

Answer (score -1):

Never try to write in the same file you are reading unless it is a direct (binary) file with block of constant size ! You could break it and hardly recover.

In your use case it is not too worse. As you use the iterator interface of the file object, Python reads a whole chunk (in fact the whole file) and the file pointer is immediately positionned at the end. The you get the line one at a time, but when you write you (hopefully) write at the end of file. If you had read the file with `readline`, your write would have overwritten following lines.

The correct way is to rename input file, open it readonly, open a new file writeonly copy and modify at will and if was ok delete input file.

The alternative simple way when the file is small, is to load everything in memory and **rewind the file** before writing all back.

```
f = open("file.txt",'r+')
lines = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if i == 2:
        f.write("Added at 2nd line")
    elif i == 3:
        f.write("Added at 2nd line")
    elif i > 29:
        break
f.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use fileinput:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=True):
  if fileimput.filelineno() == 2: 
    print line.replace(line, 'Added at 2nd line\n'),
```

or you have to write a second file:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('new_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
  for line in input_file:
    if input_file.index(line) == 1:
      output_file.write('Added at 2nd line\n')
    else:
      output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: The first one just overwrites your entire file with whatever your string is.